# How to implement a way to delete an item from a FlatList?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am not sure how to add a delete function in a FlatList. I know I can make different components, but I want to know how to do it within this one file. I've trying to figure this out for hours, but do not know how to do.

```
export default function test() {
  const [enteredGoal, setEnteredGoal] = useState(""); 
  const [courseGoals, setCourseGoals] = useState([]); 


  const goalInput = enteredText => {
    setEnteredGoal(enteredText); 
  };

  const addGoal = () => {
    setCourseGoals(currentGoals => [
      ...currentGoals,
      { key: Math.random().toString(), value: enteredGoal }
    ]);

  };

  const removeGoal = goalId => {
    setCourseGoals(currentGoals => {
      return currentGoals.filter((goal) => goal.id !== goalId);
    })
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          color="lime"
          style={styles.placeholderStyle}
          placeholder="Type here"
          placeholderTextColor="lime"
          onChangeText={goalInput} 
          value={enteredGoal} 

        />
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={courseGoals} 
        renderItem={itemData => (
          <View style={styles.listItem} >
            <Text style={{ color: "lime" }}>{itemData.item.value}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.button} onPress={addGoal}>
            Add
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to modify your code a bit to handle the delete button. Since you already have delete functionality, call that function when you click the delete button. That's it.

```
<FlatList
  data={courseGoals}
  renderItem={itemData => (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
      <Text style={{ color: "lime" }}>{itemData.item.value}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => removeGoal(itemData.item.key)}>
        <Text>Delete</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )}
/>;
```

**EDIT**
change your `removeGoal` function as below

```
const removeGoal = goalId => {
  setCourseGoals(courseGoals => {
    return courseGoals.filter(goal => goal.key !== goalId);
  });
};
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: That is deleting all the list item. I want to be able to delete each item individually.

Comment: @Swap01 I changed ```removeGoal``` function.

Comment: @Swap01 If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it.